# How do i update multiple rows(thousands) with all having different values in the lest possible time

Tags: sql, oracle

```
 UPDATE element e1 SET e1.line_number = 
    (
      SELECT t.r FROM 
        (
          select ele,rownum r from
            ( 
              select            nvl(par.SEQUENCE,ch.SEQUENCE),ch.SEQUENCE,nvl2(par.SEQUENCE,ch.SEQUENCE,0),ch.element_id ele 
              from element par right join element ch on par.element_id=ch.parent_element_id 
              where ch.document_id = 78384  order by 1,3,2
             )
         ) t ,element e1
         WHERE e1.element_id = t.ele 

     )  WHERE e1.document_id = 78384;
```

Comment: Added `oracle` tag based on the usage of `nvl()`

Comment: This has a horrible O(n2) performance. If you provide create scripts, sample data and expected output, we can show you how to do it with O(n) performance.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot directly provide the answer you were requesting, but give some hints which may help you:

- First of all, you should give us a few hints about your use case. One may guess what's happening in your statement, but it's much easier to help you if you describe what you have and what you need.
- You have 3 cascaded `select`s, which is usually not the best idea. Plus you have an `order by` in the inner select, which should not be necessary.
- Basically you want to filter all rows which needs to be updated - try to put that into a select using joins. And always use the condition first which most likely filters out the most rows.
- And always when trying to optimize a statement, have a look at the execution plan by using the [`explain plan`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28274/ex_plan.htm#i17492) command. With that you can see things like usage of full table scans or indexes. If necessary, you can then provide [optimizer hints](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16638/hintsref.htm#PFGRF005) to control the best way of executing the statement.